# Problemas com arquivo web.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, build

```
Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
```

Estou usando o Netbeans para trabalhar com um projeto Spring e ate o momento não tinha me deparado com esse aviso.

A IDE executava o projeto normalmente.
Embora use o pluggin do jetty para rodar pelo terminal , eu usava o tomcat do netbeans e a aplicação  rodava sem problemas..
Agora so roda pelo terminal com o pluggin do jetty..

Fiz umas mudanças no codigo e de repente comecei a ver essa mensagem, então  voltei varios commits quando o codigo ainda funcionava.
Para a minha surpresa a mensagem voltou a aprecer!! E não consigo rodar pela IDE netbeans
O que esta ocorrendo? E como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você usou o comtrole de versão e ate certo ponto de sua apicação tudo estava em funcionando perfeitamente.

Como alguma coisa aconteceu e essa mensagem começou  a aparecer e você voltou ao commit onde tudo funcionava bem,reconpilou e tentou implantar, mesmo assim a IDE mostra que existe um defeito, isso quer dizer que ela esta comrrompida.

Para reslver esse problema desisntale o netbeans complertamente.
"É raro" mas o netbeans corrompe seus dados de configuração  e fica mostrando essa mensagens obsoletas!